# Magento 2.3.3 - When minify the js getting the issues

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3, minified-js, js-minification

We're getting a lot of error messages on the console about missing JS libraries after minify the js in Magento 2.3.3 (on both frontend and admin). Apparently they are all related to `jquery/ui-modules`.

e.g.:

> pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery/ui-modules/timepicker.js
>
> pub/static/version/frontend/theme/en_IE/jquery-ui-modules/resizable.min.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> pub/static/version/frontend/theme/en_IE/jquery-ui-modules/slider.min.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>
> pub/static/version8/frontend/theme/en_IE/jquery-ui-modules/timepicker.min.js
> net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: confirm you set proper permission into magento.

Comment: I gave permissions to var, pub, generated folders

Comment: Are you signing your files ? https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cache/static-content-signing.html Does this happen with both: developer and production mode?

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand the issue scenario, however, I am trying to help in general. As I learn you are using Magento 2.3.3. In this Magento refactored `jQuery/ui` to separate widgets.([Details](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-3-open-source.html#ui))

All you have to do edit `requirejs-config.js` as in

```
map: {
    '*': {
        'jquery/ui: 'jquery/compat'
    }
}
```

and in

```
paths: {
    'jquery-ui-modules': 'jquery/ui-modules',
}
```

I hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set proper file permission like

and then run below command to regenerate static contents

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

and if multiple languages then add each language

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_GB nl_NL